# How to clear Smarty's Cache

Tags: php, caching, smarty

The original owner of our company had the website designed using Smartys. I have updated the product page, but even after deleting the temporary file from "templates_c" which I thought was the cache file, the updated products page will not show up at all, everything still looks exactly as it did previously.

How can I clear the cache on Smartys so my modified page will be viewable?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Smarty uses a compile directory and a separate cache directory. `templates_c` is probably the compile directory.  The cache is specified in `$smarty->cache_dir`.  That's the one you need to empty.

In PHP with Smarty version 2, you can execute the function [`clear_all_cache()`](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/api.clear.all.cache.tpl)

```
$smarty->clear_all_cache();
```

If you are using Smarty version 3, the command is [`clearAllCache()`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.clear.all.cache.tpl)

```
$smarty->clearAllCache();
```

To find out the cache directory:

```
echo $smarty->cache_dir;
```

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try that now. How is http://xfactorservers.com/game_servers/ loading a different page from http://xfactorservers.com/game_servers.php? Is that just how it caches it?